# How to create a multi dimensional array with unlimited depth as needed from the following parent-child resultset

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have the following result set

[image: results obtained from a query]

I need to create an array like this

```
array(11) {
  ["Science & engineering"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Physics"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Work & energy"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["Chemistry"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["Biology"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["Computing"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Arts & humanities"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Math"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Economics & finance"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Business"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Personal development"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Lifestyle"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Health & fitness"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Photography"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

As you can see the array is only two levels deep. I need to create an array that goes down infinite as long as there are more children and without repetition.

Edit: I will also welcome any other efficient solution to this problem. The end result should be to have a list of all categories in an array in a heiarchical order.

Answer (score 0):

example of the script you use to create the array with 2 lvl???

You'll have to use recursion structure function:

```
<?php
function buildArray(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = buildArray($elements, $element['id']); //recursion
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}

$result= buildArray($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many recursive function code examples on this site but pretty much all of them start from child and goes all the way to parents. In my case I needed to start from parent and go all the way to children.

So, I was able to solve the problem by writing a recursive function as follows:

```
            function findParentsParent($result,$category) {
            global $subs;
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                if ($row['childName'] == $category['name']) {
                    $subs[] = $category['childName'];
                    findParentsParent($result,$row);
                    return array_reverse($subs);
                } elseif ($row['childName'] == $category['childName']) {
                    $subs[] = $category['childName'];
                    $subs[] = $category['name'];
                    return array_reverse($subs);
                }
            }
        }
```